# Is this a correct way to store different types in the same allocation?

Tags: c++, void-pointers, static-cast

I need to allocate a chunk of memory using `malloc` and then store multiple values of different plain old data types in there. Is the following a correct way to do it?

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    int32_t a;
    int32_t b;
};

struct Bar {
    int8_t a;
    int8_t b;
};

void* offset_bytewise(void* void_ptr, ptrdiff_t count) {
    return static_cast<void*>(static_cast<char*>(void_ptr) + count);
}

void test() {
    auto void_ptr = std::malloc(10);
    new (offset_bytewise(void_ptr, 0)) Foo{ 1, 2 };
    new (offset_bytewise(void_ptr, 8)) Bar{ 3, 4 };
    auto foo_ptr = static_cast<Foo*>(offset_bytewise(void_ptr, 0));
    auto bar_ptr = static_cast<Bar*>(offset_bytewise(void_ptr, 8));

    std::cout << (int)foo_ptr->a << ' ' << (int)foo_ptr->b << '\n';
    std::cout << (int)bar_ptr->a << ' ' << (int)bar_ptr->b << '\n';

    // Re-using a part of the allocation as a different type than before.
    new (offset_bytewise(void_ptr, 1)) Bar{ 5, 6 };
    bar_ptr = static_cast<Bar*>(offset_bytewise(void_ptr, 1));

    // I suppose dereferencing `foo_ptr` would be UB now?

    std::cout << (int)bar_ptr->a << ' ' << (int)bar_ptr->b << '\n';
    std::free(void_ptr);
}
```

Comment: Use of `std::any` might be a solution that could help remove undefined behavior...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicit object creation will cause the allocated memory block to contain an array of `char` of suitable size and the pointer returned from `malloc` will point to the first element of that array.

(That is assuming `std::malloc` doesn't return a null pointer, which you should check for.)

Such an array can provide storage for other objects (although technically the standard currently says this is only true for `unsigned char` and `std::byte`, which is probably a defect).

So you are ok to create new objects in that array as you are doing.

However, when you try to obtain a pointer to the newly created object, you cannot simply cast the pointer since elements of the array are not pointer-interconvertible with the objects for which the array provides storage.

Therefore you need to apply `std::launder` after casting the pointer, e.g.

```
auto foo_ptr = std::launder(static_cast<Foo*>(offset_bytewise(void_ptr, 0)));
```

Alternatively you can use the result of `new` which is a pointer to the newly created object:

```
auto foo_ptr = new(offset_bytewise(void_ptr, 0)) Foo{ 1, 2 };
```

Also, you need to make sure that size and alignment of the types is correct, i.e. here you should add:

```
static_assert(alignof(Foo) <= 8);
static_assert(sizeof(Foo) <= 8);
static_assert(alignof(Bar) <= 1);
static_assert(sizeof(Bar) <= 2);
```

Creating the second `Bar` object at offset `1` will cause the lifetime of the `Foo` object to end, since it overlaps with the storage of the new object. Therefore `foo_ptr` may afterwards be used only in the way other pointers to object out-of-lifetime of an object may be used. In particular trying to access the value of a member will be UB.

Comment: I suppose an equivalent way would be to use an array of `uint8_t`/`byte` like `auto bytes_ptr = new std::byte[10];`, place an object using `new (bytes_ptr + 0) Foo{ 1, 2 };`, and then read an object using `auto foo_ptr = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(bytes_ptr + 0));` ?

Comment: @StableGeneous Yes, assuming for `uint8_t` that it is either `unsigned char` or `char`, which I guess is (always?) the case in practice. (And with the limitation for `char` I mentioned in the answer.) The alignment guarantees are a bit different from those of `std::malloc`, but I don't think it matters in practice.