# What are legal ways to construct objects in a single allocation (C++17)

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

There is a related question, [Is this a correct way to store different types in the same allocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71640163/is-this-a-correct-way-to-store-different-types-in-the-same-allocation), but I wonder if the answer is totally legal. I guess this topic is more complicated than it seems...
My question is about the following snippet where multiple objects of possibly different types are constructed with placement `new` in a single allocation in a straightforward way.

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<new>

struct A {
  int a;
  int b;
};

struct B {
  int c;
};

int main() {
  void* storage = std::malloc(1024);
  char* ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(storage);
  ptr += 16;
  new(ptr) A;
  ptr += sizeof(A);
  // construct other objects in the same way
  new(ptr) B;
}
```

First of all, according to the answer in ["constructing" a trivially-copyable object with memcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63682409), P0593 applies retrospectively.

> Shafik's answer correctly refer to p0593 which at the time of the answer was a proposal. But since then, the proposal was accepted and things got defined.

That means that an array of char has to be implicitly created to give the `reinterpret_cast` defined behavior. Thus, the pointer arithmetic `ptr += 16` is well defined too.

`new(ptr) A` replaces the part of the array from `ptr` to `ptr + sizeof(A) - 1`, *ending the lifetime of the implicitly created char elements in that range*. So I'd say, at this point, `ptr` is technically pointing to objects whose lifetime has ended and the successive pointer arithmetic `ptr += sizeof(A)` is UB.

Am I right so far? If that is the case, possible solutions would look like:
(BTW, if this is true, that menas the answer to [Is this a correct way to store different types in the same allocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71640163/is-this-a-correct-way-to-store-different-types-in-the-same-allocation) still has UB (because incrementing the pointer after `new`). )

1. `std::launder`

   ```cpp
   new(ptr) A;
   // std::launder(ptr) is now pointing to the existing `A` instance as char*.
   // This is file because a char pointer can alias anything.
   ptr = std::launder(ptr) + sizeof(A); 
   // ptr += 16; // UB
   ```

   However, it seems that this still can have UB because *`std::launder(ptr)` aliases the `A` object but is not pointing to any array object*. Pointer arithmetic on non-array objects is UB. Thus, if I did, for instance, `ptr += 128` after these lines, it would be UB.
   see also [Type punning in modern C++ - Timur Doumler - CppCon 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qzMpk-22cc&t=2647s) (from 44:10)
2. Increment `ptr` and then `new`

   ```cpp
   ptr += sizeof(A); // Increment the pointer beforehand so that ptr doesn't point to dead objects.
   new(ptr - sizeof(A)) A;
   // `ptr` is pointing to an existing char element of the implicitly created ARRAY, 
   // so it's fine to increment `ptr` after this.
   ```
3. Construct objects and then `std::memcpy` them to the storage
   I believe this is also a simple and well-defined solution.

So I guess feasible solutions would be 2 or 3, is my understanding correct? Thank you.

Comment: I hope you understand that those are purely theoretical issues, and your original code will work in practice. If your first snippet happens to be UB, then the standard is defective.

Comment: _`ptr` is technically pointing to objects whose lifetime has ended and the successive pointer arithmetic `ptr += sizeof(A)` is UB_ Why?

Comment: Because `new(ptr) A`  has replaced `char` objects and `ptr` is not `std::launder`ed yet and is still pointing the 1st one of the replaced objects, and pointer arithmetic on non-array objects (dead chars) is UB. (Of course the addresses are the same, though)

Comment: _is still pointing the 1st one of the replaced objects_ 1st what? _pointer arithmetic on non-array objects (dead chars) is UB_ Pointer arithmetic does not require pointee to be alive. Dead `char` is still an array element

Comment: I mean the 1st element of the replaced `char`s. And, "Pointer arithmetic does not require pointee to be alive. Dead char is still an array element", I didn't know this part, thank you. So that means `std::launder` is unnecessary in the first place and the option 1. was wrong...

Comment: You missed probably the easiest solution: Stick all the objects you want to create into a `struct` (or other aggregate, but you specifically wanted non-homogenous types so an array won't do) and create that just once.  Doesn't work if there are internal ragged array members.

Comment: Also note that a really simple solution to your concern about pointer arithmetic on dead chars is -- perform the arithmetic before you reuse their storage.  `auto startA = ptr; auto startB = startA + sizeof(A); new (startA) A; auto startC = startB + sizeof(B); new (startB) B;` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understand your question. You are wondering if it's possible and legal to create two different types of objects in the same block of memory, which are distributed along the block.

The answer is yes, but you must consider some important aspects:

1. You must allocate the memory as you are doing so
2. You must initialize the instance using a **placement new operator**.
3. After using a **placement new operator** you must invoke the destructor explicitly for each instance.

Using your code, this is the process:

```cpp
struct A {
  int a;
  int b;
  ~A(){cout << "~A{" << a << "," << b <<"}\n";} 
};

struct B {
  int c;
  ~B(){cout << "~B{" << c << "}\n";}
};

struct C {
  char* s;
  C(const char* si){        
        s = new char[256];
        size_t i{0};
        while(si && si[i]!='\0')
        {
            s[i] = si[i];
            i++;
        }
        cout << "C(" << s << ")\n";
    }
  ~C(){        
        cout << "~C{" << s << "}\n";
        delete[] s;
    }
};

int main()
{
    void* storage = (char*)std::malloc(1024);
    char* ptrA = reinterpret_cast<char*>(storage);;
    char* ptrB = ptrA + sizeof(A);
    char* ptrC = ptrB + sizeof(B);

    cout <<  "SA: " << sizeof(A) << "\n";
    cout <<  "SB: " << sizeof(B) << "\n";
    cout <<  "SB: " << sizeof(C) << "\n";

    A* a = ::new(ptrA) A{23,6463}; // new(prt) is the placement new operator 
    B* b = ::new(ptrB) B{333};
    C* c = ::new(ptrC) C("This is my text");

    cout << "A.a: " << a->a << "A.b: " << a->b << "\n"; 
    cout << "B.a: " << b->c << "\n"; 
    cout << "C.s: " << c->s << "\n";
    
    a->~A();
    b->~B();
    c->~C();
    
    free(storage);

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
A: 8
SB: 4
SB: 8
C(This is my text)
A.a: 23A.b: 6463
B.a: 333
~A{23,6463}
~B{333}
~C{This is my text}
```

If you use `delete` on the pointer `a`, you might get an exception for double free detection.

```cpp
delete a;
    //delete b;
    //delete c;

    //a->~A();
    //b->~B();
    //c->~C();
    
    free(storage);
```

Output:

```
A: 8
SB: 4
SB: 8
C(This is my text)
A.a: 23A.b: 6463
B.a: 333
C.s: This is my text
~A{23,6463}
Program stderr
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Program terminated with signal: SIGSEGV
```

If you are trying to release memory from another pointer different than pointer `a` you would have an exception for

```cpp
    //delete a;
    delete b;
    //delete c;
```

Output:

```
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
Program terminated with signal: SIGSEGV
```

as @ChrisDodd said, there is a significant difference between the operator `new` and `new(ptr)`. `new(ptr)` is **placement new** which means that we can pass the preallocated memory and construct the object in that block of memory. In my sample, the '::' ensures that the resolution occurs from the global namespace to avoid pickup an overlapped version of `operator new`

...Here is another link to read more about the topic:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/placement-new-operator-cpp/

> For more information, I recommend the Book **C++ High Performance** from Björn Andirst and Viktor Sehr, over the section **Memory Management**.

Comment: `new T` and `::new T` are identical unless `T` has an overloaded operator `new`.  You seem to by trying to talk about `new` vs `new(p)` (allocating new vs placement new), which is an important distinction, but has nothing to do with the presence or absence of `::`

Comment: @ChrisDodd You are right, the topic is about placement new, let me share an extract of the topic on my answer.

Comment: @ChrisDodd thanks for your comment, I've just made a double check of the concept and updated my answer.